# VB.NET - is there a way to programmatically create a scheduler just to call a certain url/api?

Tags: vb.net

I have looked everywhere but I cant really find what I wanted. Here is the scenario. I have a web application, when a user clicks a button, it will send api request to the vendor to activate a device. The problem is, the vendor does not have the api method to set start and end time for the device. So, my idea now is, once i get the "green light" from the vendor to activate the machine, i will also programmatically schedule a task in the server to call my web application after 15 minutes to turn off the device (by url with query string, www.xxxx.aspx?deviceid=123).

really appreciate the help or any pointers on how to achieve this. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the way answer is typed i am on phone right now. it was fun researching for it and i would like to hear from you if it works

So assuming you have access to your api.

The way i think you can make it work is by using a backgroundworker in your api / web application it is a nuget you download to your web application

If you open and  scroll in that link it has example talking about having background task similar to windows task schedular however for any type of webapplication it is open source project called backgroundworker and many task schedulers you can add on web application  give it a try

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx